# Data put into Dropdown

Tags: php, html, css, mysql

I want to get the Data from MySQL and insert it in my Navbar. My Problem is that some data has to put under the dropdown but it create a new main listitem.

Here is the Screenshot how it looks like now but I want that the `Panel` column insert in the Dropdown Menu.

[image]

```
    <?php 
     $query  =   $connect->prepare("SELECT * FROM `ucp_navbar` WHERE `Kategorie` = 0");
     $query->execute();
    ?>

<div class='collapse navbar-collapse' id='bs-example-navbar-collapse-1'>
<ul class='nav navbar-nav'>
    <?php while ($row = $query->fetch()) { echo $row["Panel"]; if($row["Panel"] == 0) { ?>
        <li <?php if($page_a == $row["Active"]) echo "class='active nav-active'"; ?>>
            <a href='<?php echo htmlentities($row["Link"]); ?>'><i class='fa fa-<?php echo htmlentities($row["Icon"]); ?>' aria-hidden='true'></i> <?php echo htmlentities($row["Name"]); ?></a>
        </li><?php } ?>

        <?php if($row["Panel"] != 0 && $row["Panel"] == 1) { ?>
        <li class='dropdown'>
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><i class='fa fa-user' aria-hidden='true'></i> Account<span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li>
                    <a href='<?php echo htmlentities($row["Link"]); ?>'><i class='fa fa-<?php echo htmlentities($row["Icon"]); ?>' aria-hidden='true'></i> <?php echo htmlentities($row["Name"]); ?></a>
                </li>
            </ul>        
        </li>
    <?php } } ?>
</ul>
```

My Database structure:

[image: Database_structure]

Comment: Maybe i'm missing something but how do you know which dropdown its supposed to go under? if Panel == 1 then does it go under all dropdowns? According to the first image you have two dropdowns called Account. The DB structure does not indicate which ones are dropdown. Most of the time when doing this you should have a parent child relationship in there where instead of panel maybe that should be the id of the "Parent" that this link shows up under and if it is 0 then it is not a dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue you are running into is that you are treating submenus the same as main navbar items. Below is a possible solution, I've done some heavy format refactoring to try and bring the logic portion to the top so that the solution is more clear. I would tend to agree with the earlier commenter (@Scott) that creating a parent child relationship of tables would be the more maintainable practice long term.

```
<?php 
// Make query
$query = $connect->prepare("SELECT * FROM `ucp_navbar` WHERE `Kategorie` = 0");
$query->execute();

// Setup containers for list items
$nav = array();
$dropdown = array();

// Iterate query
while ($row = $query->fetch()) {
  // Assign built list item to either navbar or dropdown arrays
  switch ($row['Panel']) {
    case 0:
      $nav[] = buildListItem(
        htmlentities($row['Link']),
        htmlentities($row['Icon']),
        echo htmlentities($row["Name"]),
        true
      );
      break;
    case 1:
      $dropdown[] = buildListItem(
        htmlentities($row['Link']),
        htmlentities($row['Icon']),
        echo htmlentities($row["Name"])
      ); 
  }  
}

// Add dropdowns to main nav and convert array of nav items to string.
$nav[] = buildDropdown($dropdowns);
$navbar = implode("", $nav);

/**
 * Builds an individual list item.
 *
 * @param string $link URL to use for href
 * @param string $icon font-awesome icon to use
 * @param string $name display name for navbar
 * @param bool   $active adds nav-active class when true
 *
 * @return string formatted single list item
 */
function buildListItem($link, $icon, $name, $active = false)
{
  $class = ($active) ? ' class="active nav-active"': ""
  return "<li{$class}><a href=\"{$link}\"><i class=\"fa fa-{$icon}\" aria-hidden=\"true\"></i>{$name}</a></li>";
}

/**
 * Construct dropdown list item.
 *
 * @param array $dropdowns group of dropdown list items 
 *
 * @return string formatted dropdown list for navbar
 */
function buildDropdown($dropdowns)
{
  $list = implode("", $dropdowns);
  return <<<EOT 
  <li class='dropdown'>
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        <i class='fa fa-user' aria-hidden='true'></i> 
        Account<span class="caret"></span>
      </a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          $list
      </ul>        
  </li>
EOT;
}
?>

<div class='collapse navbar-collapse' id='bs-example-navbar-collapse-1'>
<ul class='nav navbar-nav'>
   <?php echo $navbar; ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank's Dude I tested it and it works!
Thank's a lot, now I know how I have to handle the dynamically Dropdowns :)